# Assigning a value to a variable containing a colon in Perl

Tags: perl, csv

I wrote this nifty Perl script to generate a .cue file for a radio station's automation system.  It worked the first day I wrote it and a week later it does not work.

Here is the pseudo-code of how it works:

1. Call script and assign the following variables as a parameter at start up:
   --name of CSV file to be imported into array
   --name of MP3 file
2. I declare the names of variables that the comma separated values will be assigned to
3. Open file
4. In a while loop, I iterate through each line of the CSV and assign each comma separated value to a variable.  Before I move to the next iteration, I print on the screen the output for the .cue file
5. Iterate through the while loop until all the lines of the CSV have been processed

Here is the problem,  in my CSV, I the last field has a value containing a colon and Perl thinks its an operator.  Here is a sample line:

No One Like You,Scorpions,Blackout,13:38:00

When I run the script I get the following error:
syntax error at part1.csv line 4, near "13:"

Here is my question: How do I assign to a variable a string that contains a : operator? It appears that when Perl is seeing the string with the colon in it, it thinks that it needs to do something with : instead of just passing it into the variable.

I am running active state perl on Windows 10.  Here is my

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";
my $mp3Filename = $ARGV[1] or die "Need the MP3 File Name\n";
my $title;
my $performer;
my $remAlbum;
my $myTrackIndex;
my $line;
my $data;
my @fields;
my $track = 1;
#FILE "show1.mp3" WAVE
print "FILE \"$ARGV[1]\" WAVE\n";
open($data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {
chomp $line;
my @fields = split "," , $line;
$title = $fields[0];
$performer = $fields[1];
$remAlbum = $fields[2];
$myTrackIndex = $fields[3];
print "TRACK 0$track AUDIO\n";
print "TITLE \"$title\"\n";
print "PERFORMER \"$performer\"\n";
print "REM ALBUM \"$remAlbum\"\n";
print "INDEX 01 $myTrackIndex\n";
$track++;
#TRACK 01 AUDIO
#TITLE "Heavy Metal Halloween - Toccata And Fugue"
#PERFORMER "Heavy Metal Halloween"
#REM ALBUM "Heavy Metal Halloween"
#INDEX 01 00:02:00



}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
Semicolon seems to be missing at part1.csv line 1.
 at part1.csv line 1.
Semicolon seems to be missing at part1.csv line 2.
 at part1.csv line 2.
Semicolon seems to be missing at part1.csv line 3.
 at part1.csv line 3.
Semicolon seems to be missing at part1.csv line 4.
 at part1.csv line 4.
Semicolon seems to be missing at part1.csv line 5.
 at part1.csv line 5.
syntax error at part1.csv line 1, near "00:"
syntax error at part1.csv line 2, near "05:"
Illegal octal digit '9' at part1.csv line 3, at end of line
syntax error at part1.csv line 3, near "09:"
syntax error at part1.csv line 4, near "13:"
syntax error at part1.csv line 5, near "17:"
syntax error at part1.csv line 6, near "24:"
Execution of part1.csv aborted due to compilation errors.
 at part1.csv line 6.
```

Thanks for your patience.  Its been quite a few years since I have written any code.

Comment: Tip: You have a lot a bugs in your parsing of the CSV file. You should use Text::CSV. It's not any longer to use, and it will correctly parse your CSV.  Usage: `my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 }); while (my $fields = $csv->getline($data)) { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

The error-message indicates a problem with how Perl is being invoked. It's trying to run `part1.csv` as a Perl program (instead of running your actual Perl program).

```
perl -d part1.csv EJHour1-1.mp3
```

should be

```
perl script.pl part1.csv EJHour1-1.mp3
```

or just

```
script.pl part1.csv EJHour1-1.mp3
```